# Any idea why all my data are in the first column of the dataframe and the rest are NaN?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
```

> Reading the CV File and adding the columns

```
data = pd.read_csv('e-shop clothing 2008.csv')
data.columns = [col.strip() for col in data.columns]
data.columns
```

> The output of data.columns is that:

```
Index(['year;month;day;order;country;session ID;page 1 (main category);page 2 (clothing model);colour;location;model photography;price;price 2;page'], dtype='object')
```

> Creating new columns

```
features = ['year', 'month', 'day', 'order', 'country', 'session_id', 'main_category_page1', 'clothing_model_page2', 'color', 'location', 'model_photography', 'price', 'price_2', 'page']

new_data = pd.read_csv('e-shop clothing 2008.csv', sep='\t',names= features)
new_data.head()
```

> And I get that. All the data in one column and the rest are NaN
> [Click here to see the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3eyZJ.png)

> Any idea of how I could solve it so I don't have all the data in one column and the rest NaN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the `separator` in your csv is `;`. You have to explicitly pass it. Do this:

```
data = pd.read_csv('e-shop clothing 2008.csv', sep=';')
```

If you don't pass an explicit separator, `pd.read_csv` will take comma(`,`) as the separator. Hence your file has everything in just one column and rest are `NaN`.

Comment: That did the trick. I didn't realised that I had a different separator. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

As already noted your file is `;`-seperated, so to read correctly you need to inform `pandas` about that. I want to add that you might specify `sep` as `None` in [pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) to make it guess what seperator is used in file.